# Django extended UserProfile model is not saving my extra informations

Tags: python, django

I have a UserProfile model extending contrib.auth.User, and when I try to save it, the extra information I added in the profile is not saved.

Here is Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='profile')
    cellphone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            profile, created = 
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

And forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    cellphone = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # fields = ('cellphone', )
        fields = ('username', 'cellphone', 'email', 'password', )
```

And finally my view.py

```
def register(request):
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.profile.cellphone = form.cleaned_data['cellphone']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'user/index.html', {'user': user})
    else:
        return render(request, 'user/register.html', {'form': form, })
```

I couldn't figure out why it is not saving the cellphone attribute.

Comment: Your cellphone field is from `UserProfile` model. But your `UserProfileForm` is modelform for `User`. So I guess you don't have cellphone data in your `cleaned_data`. Could you check it?

Comment: Hello seuling, yes so in my database it's only saving the attributes from User and the cellphone is null for all the users. I'm trying to figure out how can I save the user and a userprofile related to it together. Thank you

Comment: inherit from django `abstract.user` instead of `models.model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `user.profile.save()` in view after `user.profile.cellpone = ...` line.